# tensorflow: one-class classification

Tags: tensorflow, classification, deep-learning

I'm trying to adapt the tutorial [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html) to detect just one class, let's say detect if an image contains or not a kitty.

This is the prediction part of my code:

```
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(20000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

The problem is that with one class, the softmax always return that class with confidence of 1, even for a blank image.
I tried modifying the softmax and cross entropy, but I wasn't able to solve it.

I need to know what approach is recommended for this problem.
I want the prediction to be the probability of an image being a kitty.

I know that this can be solved using a second label trained with random images, but I need to know if there is a better solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, could you provide the whole code? Also, how many train and test images per class are you using?

Comment: The whole code is the one in the tutorial, I'm using 50K images for training 5K for testing. All the images belongs to an unique class.

Comment: You have two classes, kitty and not kitty, so its binary classification.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you for your answer, I tried to use 2 labels, but I trained it only with 50K images of kitties, it still predicts any image as a kitty. I also have to train it with random images without kitties? Thanks

Comment: @cropmad1548You tried, then what did you use for non-kitty images? In that case yes, you should introduce random non-kitty images.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use softmax and multi-class logloss for a single class membership prediction. Instead, the more usual setup is sigmoid activation with binary cross entropy. Unless you are optimising cost/benefit of correct prediction*, just set a threshold value of > 0.5 to be classified as the "positive" class.

In TensorFlow, this changes your code in only a couple of places.

The following adjustments apply to the start of your code I think:

```
y_conv = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

# I've split the individual loss out because the line length was too long
# The +1e-12 is for numerical stability in case of perfect 0.0 or 1.0 predictions
# Note how this loss metric penalises incorrect predictions in both directions,
# unlike the multiclass logloss which only assessed confidence in
# correct class.
loss = -(y_ * tf.log(y_conv + 1e-12) + (1 - y_) * tf.log( 1 - y_conv + 1e-12))
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(loss, reduction_indices=[1]))

predict_is_kitty = tf.greater(y_conv,0.5)
correct_prediction = tf.equal( tf.to_float(predict_is_kitty), y_ )
```

---

* If you are working on a problem where you care about confidence of the prediction, and need to assess where to set the threshold, the usual metric instead of accuracy is [area under ROC curve, often known as AUROC or just AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic).

Comment: the problem is that his data contains 1 class!  if you train with this, the output will always be 1 or whatever value you assign to that one class regardless of the input.

Comment: @thang: Actually the OP has two classes (cat or not cat) and a single binary label, but was trying to use softmax with one *output*. They could either use two outputs with softmax (and one-hot encode their true/false classes e.g. [1,0] for false, [0,1] for true), or one output with sigmoid as per my answer and use labels [0], [1]

Comment: OP keeps bringing up 1 class.  I assume that he has two classes, but his training data contains only 1.  This is typically  called the one class classification problem (OCC). In this case, during training, regardless of whether you use 2 output with xentropy softmax or 1 output with 0 and 1, the training will always converge to a degenerate solution with only 1 class training data.  OCC is slightly different, and the same supervised training regime would not work.

Comment: @thang: OK right I get you it may not be about labels, but about the training set. In which case my answer is indeed missing something. However, the use of `softmax` in the question is still likely incorrect (with one output it will always predict 1 as the OP complains, even with both classes represented properly in the training data), and my answer still covers that part of it. Sadly the OP has given no feedback on this answer, so it is not 100% clear whether they also need to look at OCC.